# Printing .csv file as list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

My Code:

```
import csv

with open('serialnumber.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    your_list = list(reader)

print(your_list)
```

.csv file:

```
hello,bye
```

Printed output :

```
[['hello', 'bye']]
```

I need to get list like this :

```
['hello', 'bye']
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: output : `<_csv.reader object at 0x00482E30>`

Comment: What happens if you change the name of the variable you're storing the output of `csv.reader()`?

Comment: do you want to print the whole csv file as a list or just row by row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting `[["hello", "bye"]]` is because, if the CSV has multiple lines, they will be items inside the first list.

You can get what you want by accessing the first item of `your_list` like this:

```
>>> print(your_list[0])
["hello", "bye"]
```

Comment: It works. I was trying to solve this one hour before i ask question here. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem with your code. It is just that you are making a list out of all rows of the csv. That is why you are getting a list of lists. To get each row as a list you can simply iterate over the reader and you will get a list for each row. This technique is particularly useful when you have a large file.

```
import csv

with open('serialnumber.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for r in reader:
      print r
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see a two-dimensional array of CSV file

`[print(r) for r in your_list]`

```
    import csv

with open('serialnumber.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    your_list = list(reader)

#print(your_list)
[print(r) for r in your_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to flatten the whole **csv reader** i would use [**`list comprehenstion`**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
import csv

with open('serialnumber.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    _list = [word for _iter in reader for word in _iter]
print(_list)
```

You could also use [**`sum`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
_list = sum(reader, [])
```

Example one row **csv**:

```
hello,bye
```

Output:

```
['hello', 'bye']
```

Example multi-row **csv**:

```
hello,bye,bye
bye,bye,hello
bye,hello,bye
```

Output:

```
['hello', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'bye', 'hello', 'bye', 'hello', 'bye']
```

If your csv file has just one row you could use plain [**`print`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print):

```
import csv

with open('serialnumber.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    print(*reader)
```